# How to catch exception in twisted Deferred callback?

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

```
    from twisted.internet import reactor, defer

def getDummyData(x):
    """
    This function is a dummy which simulates a delayed result and
    returns a Deferred which will fire with that result. Don't try too
    hard to understand this.
    """
    d = defer.Deferred()
    # simulate a delayed result by asking the reactor to fire the
    # Deferred in 2 seconds time with the result x * 3
    reactor.callLater(2, d.callback, x * 3)
    return d

def printData(d):
    """
    Data handling function to be added as a callback: handles the
    data by printing the result
    """
    raise ValueError('IIIGGAA')
    print d

def nextCall(d):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
d = getDummyData(3)

d.addErrback(nextCall).addCallback(printData).addErrback(nextCall).addCallback(nextCall)


# manually set up the end of the process by asking the reactor to
# stop itself in 4 seconds time
reactor.callLater(1, reactor.stop)
# start up the Twisted reactor (event loop handler) manually
reactor.run()
```

function nextCall - never calls. So were I can find my ValueError?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's never called because the code under your comment that says it asks the reactor to stop itself in **4** seconds actually asks the reactor to stop itself in **1** second.  The 2-second `callLater` never gets called, so `d` is never fired, so `nextCall` is never called.

Maybe you should try constructing this example without use of the reactor, just by calling `callback` on the appropriate deferred synchronously?  You don't need the reactor to fire a simple `Deferred` and messing around with them synchronously can help to give you a more precise idea of what exactly happens when.